# Replacing Screen lock in android

Tags: android

I would like to know is there any possibility to replace default lock screen and developing our own locking application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will require you to create your own android firmware. You cannot do it in a simple application.

Comment: I was not familiar with this application, but reading the information in the supplied link, it is clear that they had big problems with it (and last version is over a year ago)